# Can I specify pre-generated playlists for Google+'s YouTube integration?

Tags: youtube, google-plus, youtube-playlist

Google+ [recently added some amount of YouTube integration](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/shipping-google-in-google.html) in the form of a fly-out widget which lets you create playlists off of YouTube search queries.

When sharing a video from one of those playlists, you get a nice big button in the post which allows your followers to play the playlist directly in Google+:

[image: Google+ YouTube Integration]

This is all well and good if you just want to search for anything related to a keyword on YouTube, but YouTube has its own playlist functionality where you can individually specify what videos are added.

Is there a way to get the new playlist behavior on Google+ for pre-generated YouTube playlists?

Answer (score 1):

No, currently this is not possible to do within Google Plus UI

If you would like you could suggest the feature by using the [Google Plus Moderator Page](http://www.google.com/moderator/#16/e=9fe9f)